# Make MFC form active

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have application that is inactive. I need to activate it on timer event. What function I need to call? `this->SetActiveWindow()` does't helps.

Comment: Please don't submit duplicate questions.  You asked this earlier in the same day.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

it should work on all Windows.